# displaying alert message in angular when move to other tab

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm fairly new to Angular and need to solve what seems to be a simple problem: show an alert or confirmation message on navigating between tabs in angular bootstrap. the issue is when moving to another tab, the tab will open first and then show an alert message if clicked on cancel it will back to the previous tab, what I want simply is to not leave the current tab until click on confirmation to leave.

```html
<ul ngbNav #navWithIcons="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="activeTab" class="nav-tabs">

  <li ngbNavItem="docs">
    <a ngbNavLink (click)="navigateTab('docs')">

      <span [data-feather]="'file-text'"></span>Documents</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <p>
        any content
      </p>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
  <li ngbNavItem="external">
    <a ngbNavLink (click)="navigateTab('external')">


      <span [data-feather]="'chrome'"></span> External
      Resource</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <p>
        any external link
      </p>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="navWithIcons" class="mt-2"></div>
```

**TS:**

```js
navigateTab(navTab: string) {

    if (navTab != this.currentTab) {

        if (this.isInputUpdated) {//if there is an update on the current tab inputs then
            this.confirmationMessage(true, this.currentTab);
            this.isInputUpdated = false;
        }
        this.currentTab = navTab;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to navChange event on the ngbNav element and stop the event from propagating

```html
<ul ngbNav #navWithIcons="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="activeTab" class="nav-tabs" (navChange)="navChanged($event)">
...
</ul>
```

```js
navChanged(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

Inside the confirmationMessage method, if clicked on confirm set active tab with the value of currentTab